# Appending python dictionaries, without replacing if the value is empty

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, append, overwrite

```
dict1 = {"Country":"",
         "State":"California"}

dict2 = {"Country":"United_states",
        "State":""}
```

I need to add `dict2`'s value to `dict1` so that `dict1` will be

```
dict1
>>>{u"Country":"United_states", 
    u"State":"California"}
```

If I just do `dict1.update(dict2)` or something similar, it will end up

```
dict1
>>>{u"Country":"United_states", 
    u"State":""}
```

As the empty value in `dict2` 's "State" overwrites the "States" key

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is probably with a dict comprehension that filters out the empty values:

```
dict1.update({k: v for k, v in dict2.items() if v})
```

---

If you don't understand how this works, you can translate the dict comprehension into an explicit loop:

```
filtered_dict2 = {}
for k, v in dict2.items():
    if v:
        filtered_dict2[k] = v
dict1.update(filtered_dict2)
```

---

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might want to write a wrapper function. For example, IIRC, Celery has a helper function something like this:

```
def dictfilter(pred, d=None):
    """dictfilter(d) -- returns a dict with all non-empty values from d
    dictfilter(pred, d) -- returns a dict with all values from d where pred(v)"""
    if d is None:
        return {k: v for k, v in pred.items() if v}
    else:
        return {k: v for k, v in d.items() if pred(v)}
```

<sub>(Yes, that interface, like any interface with an optional first argument and a mandatory last argument, is horrible, but it's intended to be compatible with the built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), which goes back to Python 1.x and is way too late to change…)</sub>

Then you can do:

```
dict1.update(dictfilter(dict2))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that dictionary comprehensions were only introduced in Python 2.7, so use one of the alternatives if you need to support 2.6 or earlier.

Comment: Ok sorry maybe I shoul've specified, I also want empty `""` values to still be empty values if they were empty in both dictionaries, so if `dict1` and `dict2` both had a 3rd `key:value` of for example `"city":""` then I want the final dictionary to still have `"city":""`

Comment: @FanMa: Have you tried this code? That's exactly what it does. In that case, the dictionary passed to `update` won't have a `"city"` key in it, so the existing `"city": ""` will be left alone by the `update`.

Comment: @PeterGibson: Yes, the usual alternative is to pass a genexpr to the `dict` constructor: `dict1.update(dict((k, v) for k, v in dict2.items() if v))`. However, `dict.update` has been able to take any iterable of pairs since I think 2.4, so you can just leave the `dict` off: `dict1.update((k, v) for k, v in dict2.items() if v). But really, there's not that much excuse for using 2.6 for new projects anymore. 2.7, sometimes; 2.6, very rarely.

Comment: Yes I tried your code, I found the problem. Cause when you say `if v:`, you are checking if `v` is `None` which is different from an empty string which is what I am looking for. Basically I just changed it to `if v!="":` and it worked. Thanks for the dandy wrapper though, will be using that for sure in the future (modifying it to suit project needs)

Comment: @FanMa: No, `if v` means "if `v` is _anything truthy_". `None` and `""` are both equally falsy (along with any numeric `0` or any other empty collection).

Comment: yes I think you're right, I changed something else in my code and tried both `if v:` and `if v!="":` and they both worked

Answer (score 2):

You can `filter` the second dictionary, and then update:

```
dict1 = {"Country":"", "State":"California"}
dict2 = {"Country":"United_states", "State":""}

dict1.update(filter(lambda x: x[1] is not '', dict2.items()))

print(dict1)
# {'Country': 'United_states', 'State': 'California'}
```